# This link has been removed

Tags: sharepoint-online, links, sharing-link

Is there any way we can tell where this SharePoint link pointing?
I know this is a pdf file, but not sure why the copy link option gives this type of link structure?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Sharing Links have some odd characters structure in it.

e.g. https://<TenantName>.sharepoint.com/**:w:/r**/sites/<SiteName>/<LibraryName>/<FileName.ext>?**d=**<RandomCharacters>?**csf=**<Number>?**e=**<RandomCharacters>

This is the first character you’ll come across.

- **/:w** – Microsoft Word
- **/:x** – Microsoft Excel
- **/:p** – Microsoft PowerPoint
- **/:o** – Microsoft OneNote
- **/:b** – PDF document
- **/:t** – Text document
- **/:i** – Image
- **/:v** – Video file
- **/:f** – Folder
- **/:u** – Unidentified file type

After the file type, the characters directly after indicate who the file is shared to and whether the file was shared as a read-only or editable file.

- **/:r** – Utilizes the permissions already on the file and indicates a read-only view
- **/:s** – Utilizes the permissions already on the file and indicates an editable view
- **/:t** – Shared with specific people
- **/:u** – Shared with people in your organization
- **/:g** – Shared with everyone

Finally, you’ll also find some parameters at the end of the URL (after the ? character).

- **d=** parameter allows the document to be open in Office Online in the browser for people who already have access (i.e. **/:r** or **/:s** shares).
- **e=** parameter is used to identify the document. For example, if you share a document, then rename or move it within your library, your sharing link will still work due to the seemingly random characters that follow.
- **email=** if you shared your file with one person, their email will be displayed after this parameter.
- **Web=1** opens the file in the browser
- **csf=** only shows on links that are shared with people who already have access (i.e. **/:r** or **/:s** shares).

You’ll also notice that the URL structure changes depending on the sharing option you choose. For links you create for people who already have access (i.e. **/:r** or **/:s** shares), the URL will include the path to the filename (which is the same as the example at the start of this article). For all other sharing options, the path is removed and random characters will follow the site name. For example:

e.g. https://<TenantName>.sharepoint.com/**:w:/g**/sites/<SiteName>/<RandomCharacters>?**e=**<RandomCharacters>

Reference Link:

- https://cresyl.eu/en/office-365/understanding-how-share-links-are-built/

Comment: Thanks, Dikesh. If you look at the URL I provided, the only thing that makes sense to me is the site name, and after that, I cant see the Doc Lib name or the file name?

Comment: See this https://cresyl.eu/en/office-365/understanding-how-share-links-are-built/ link for more information. It has given same hyperlink as yours in example.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find all links in a document library, this code will do that for you. You can then test or verify these links for broken links (you can send the output to a tab delimited file:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Interactive
$link_arr = @() #output will go here. 
$Items = (Get-PnPListItem -List $list_name  -PageSize 2500).FieldValues 
foreach($Item in $Items){
  if ($Item.File_x0020_Type -eq "url" ){
    # following line can be modified to just return the url
    $file_text= Get-PnPFile -Url $Item.FileRef -AsString
    $link_arr += [PSCustomObject] @{
      'ID' = $Item.ID
      'FileName'   = $Item.FileLeafRef
      'List' = $list_name
      'ShortcutUrl' = $Item._ShortcutUrl.Url;
      'CurrentLink' = $file_text)
     }
}
```